# Importing Openpyxl in one file works but in another file ModuleNotFoundError Comes

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, importerror

I have imported openpyxl in my test `.py` file. It work great in that file but when I import it in the software it shows this error:

> C:\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Wash & Fold Laundry Billing System/main.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Wash & Fold Laundry Billing System\main.py", line 5, in 
> from openpyxl import Workbook
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
> Process finished with exit code 1

I have tried each and every question in stackoverflow, google, w3schools, and geeksforgeeks
but all the answers were in vain.

Comment: have you installed openpyxl?

Comment: Yes.I have installed openpyxl

Comment: Based on the exception `No module named 'openpyxl'` it suggests Python cannot find it. Perhaps uninstall & then install openpyxl. Also check there is no sort of caching

Comment: I have created a separate venv and also installed uninstalled many times

Comment: @Greg What is Caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I Tried Everything and this one solution is the best.

You Just Have To Delete all the configurations(pycharm) or Interpreters.